# Type bounds / polymorphism confusion

Tags: scala, types

I (kinda) understand the basics of Scala's type system, but not nearly well enough! Why aren't the return types of the two functions below considered equivalent?

```
trait Base[T]
case class Foo() extends Base[Foo]
case class Bar() extends Base[Bar]

def willNotCompile[T <: Base[_]](x: Int): T =
  if(x < 10) new Foo() else new Bar()

def compilesFine(x: Int): Base[_] =
  if(x < 10) new Foo() else new Bar()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of the first function states that for *all* `T` that anybody picks (as long as they are a subtype of `Base`), the funciton has to return a value of *that* type `T`. The latter function does not promise anything like that, it only returns type `Base`. (I don't actually think that the type parameter to `Base` is relevant for this example.)

For example, consider me defining:

```
case class Baz() extends Base[Baz]
```

Then the type of `willNotCompile` would allow me to call

```
willNotCompile[Baz](0)
```

and I should get back a value of type `Baz`! Clearly, that's not the case, so the definition does not type-check.

The other function doesn't state to return anything of more specific type than `Base`, so there is no issue.

FWIW, this example demonstrates that parametric polymorphism (a.k.a. "generics") is more expressive than mere subtyping.

Answer (score 2):

The return type of `willNotCompile` is determined by the caller. Therefore, `T` may not be a supertype of `Foo` and `Bar` and thus it will not compile (consider `case class Baz() extends Base[Baz]; willNotCompile[Baz](42)`).

The return type of `compilesFine` is always `Base[_]`.